# Storing navigation structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a way to store nested navigation structure. I don't want to use database for it, storing tree-like structures there causes a lot of headache.

I need some separate place to store this structure like text file, that i can easily change during development.

What are my best options? YAML? XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally tend to throw complex navigation structures into a helper and call it good. If you do want it external, however, I'd throw together a config/nav.yml file:

```
- text: Home
  url: 'root_path'
- text: Colors
  url: 'colors_path'
  nodes:
    - text: Blue
      url: 'blue_path'
    - text: Red
      url: 'red_path'
```

Then when the project is loaded it would load the yaml file into a global constant:

```
NAV = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'nav.yml'))
```

Then in the view you would iterate over the `NAV` constant.